# Need to add LinkedIn and GitHub badges in Profile page of Stack Overflow

Tags: support, profile-page

I saw a profile page of a developer in Stack Overflow and I wanted to do have badges of LinkedIn and GitHub in my about me section too.

Please refer to the below image.

---

[image]

---

Can anyone please let me know how to add a LinkedIn link with LinkedIn symbol / badge in the about me section in Profile Page.

Comment: probably done with an simple image.

Comment: No, I don't think so, It seems like a link. Something similar to badges in readme file. Here is the link to that developer profile page. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1602555/karol-dowbecki)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is what the [relevant html from their about me looks like](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1177633?opt.textResults=true):

```html
<p>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/[removed]" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVE0j.png" alt="linkedin"> LinkedIn
  </a> &nbsp; 
  <a href="https://github.com/[removed]" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tskMh.png" alt="github"> Github
  </a>
</p>
```

if we markdown that again we get:

```
[![Linkedin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVE0j.png) LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/)
&nbsp;
[![GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tskMh.png) GitHub](https://github.com/)
```

and that will render as:

[[image: Linkedin] LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/)
  
[[image: GitHub] Github](https://github.com/)

Comment: Awesome! It worked :) Thanks for the help

Comment: @rene May I ask how to know the URL for Linkedin & GitHub badges? It seems it's a image gallery where I could also find other badges, i.e., StackOverflow.

Comment: @hmhuang they were already present in the html. i.stack.imgur.com is the stack exchange image storage service, powered by Imgur. But unlike Imgur, i.stack.imgur.com doesn't have a public page or index page or search so you can't find images that way. You either have the url or you find an url in a post / about me / comment. If all fails you can upload an image your self when editing or creating a post.